# Does eval() first makes a literal translation of the evaluated string?

Tags: javascript, json, eval, quotes

Try to execute the following code in your browser:

```
eval("(function() { console.log(JSON.parse('" + JSON.stringify('THIS IS COOL') + "')); })()");
```

it should print out `THIS IS COOL`,
however, if you execute this:

```
eval("(function() { console.log(JSON.parse('" + JSON.stringify('THIS IS "NOT" COOL') + "')); })()");
```

it will fail, instead of printing `THIS IS "NOT" COOL`

Can someone explain why this happens?

---

Take note of this:

The result of `JSON.stringify('THIS IS "NOT" COOL')` is the string `"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"`

If you try to execute `JSON.parse("THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL")`, it will fail and that is because the JS parser will interpret the string `"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"` as `"THIS IS "NOT" COOL"`.

If you execute `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('THIS IS "NOT" COOL'))`, it will work, because the string `"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"` is passed directly to `JSON.parse`.

Why does it work on this scenario, but it doesn't on the previous one?

My only conclusion is that eval explicitly unescapes everything that gets passed to it before executing the code, but I would like to know that for sure and to understand why does eval is designed to work like this.

Comment: your second code does the same thing without the eval...

Comment: [`eval()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.1) at Annotated ES5...

Comment: @dandavis I see, the thing with the eval is that I need it to evaluate the returned string from JSON.stringify on a string context.

Comment: @Teemu Nice, thanks, so 'to be safe', do you think it will suffice to do something like `eval(code.replace(/\/g, '\\\\'));` ?

Comment: @almosnow I doubt `eval` would ever be a safe solution to any problem...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is character escaping. Look at the result of the string concatenation:

```
"(function() { console.log(JSON.parse('"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"')); })()"
```

Note that this is the actual output, this is *not* a string literal. `\` is a literal character here, not the escape character (I only included the outer quotation marks to indicate that I am talking about a string).

Using `eval`, the string is evaluated as this code:

```
(function() { 
    console.log(JSON.parse('"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"')); 
})()
```

At this point, the `\"` are actually interpreted as character escape sequences, i.e. the **value** of the string *literal* `'"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"'` is:

```
"THIS IS "NOT" COOL"
```

which is an invalid JSON encoded string.

Hence you get the error

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token N`

---

`eval` does not do anything to the string you pass, it is interpreted the way it gets it.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I would think that eval actually does something because `eval("(function() { console.log(JSON.parse('" + JSON.stringify('THIS IS "NOT" COOL') + "')); })()");` does not work.

Comment: What's the difference? If I compare the code from your comment with the second example in your question its identical. Maybe my introduction wasn't clear. The string value at the beginning is the *result of running `"(function() { console.log(JSON.parse('" + JSON.stringify('THIS IS "NOT" COOL') + "')); })()"`.

Comment: JSON.stringify returns `"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"` not `"THIS IS "NOT" COOL"`. It shouldn't get unescaped because the parser is not invoked, I'm not writing the string `"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"` explicitly.

Comment: Yes, `JSON.stringify` returns that string. Then you are concatenating it with another string. And the result to the concatenation is passed to `eval`.

Comment: I think that eval calls for an 'extra' round of unescaping before executing the code.

Comment: No it doesn't. Can't you follow my answer? The second code snippet shows the code that is actually executed. Have a look at the string literal. The ``\`` are now interpreted as escape characters. The **string literal** `'"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"'` creates the string **value** `"THIS IS "NOT" COOL"`.

Comment: Try this: `JSON.parse('"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"')` and this `JSON.parse('"THIS IS \\"NOT\\" COOL"')`. The latter is the equivalent of `eval("(function() { console.log(JSON.parse('" + JSON.stringify('THIS IS "NOT" COOL') + "')); })()");`

Comment: No it is not. The `eval` call is equivalent to the first, `JSON.parse('"THIS IS \"NOT\" COOL"')`. The second code snippet in my answer shows you the code that is executed by `eval`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that string literals only get parsed (converted to string values) when you literally write them on the code.

Comment: Well, `eval` is taking a string and interprets it like you've written the code. So if that string *literally* contains a backslash, it will be evaluated as escape character by `eval`. Simple example: `eval('alert("quote: \\"");')`. The *value* of `'alert("quote: \\"");'` is `alert("quote: \"");`. When pass this to `eval`, `alert(...)` will be a function call and `"quote: \""` is a string literal whose value is `quote: "`.

Comment: Thus, eval calls for an 'extra' round of unescaping before executing the code.

Comment: Ah, now I get you. So you are asking whether you have to escape all escape characters? Yeah, it seems like that. But `eval` doesn't unescape anything (like you claimed first) it evaluates the string like you pass it.